# Export a specific Active Directory group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group |
  select @{Expression={$Group};Label="Group Name"}, Name |
  Export-Csv C:\Srptupd\Groupmembers.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

The group name I want to try to export is called "IT Staff".

Everytime I run the command, I get this error:

```
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the 
command again.
At line:3 char:23
+ Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group | select  @{Expression={$Group};Label="Group Name"} ...
+                       ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Comment: The error message is actually rather self-explanatory. Your variable `$Group` is empty. How do you populate it?

Comment: well I hard coded it before i swapped it for a variable

Comment: It's clearly not possible that you got this error message from a hard-coded group name. Please post your actual code, not something you fabricated or typed from memory. If your code uses variables, show how the variables are assigned values.

Comment: You know I had a typo when I hard coded it. I spelled Group wrong.

Comment: So the problem has resolved itself?